# trigger ref.onDiconnect() after ref.off()

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-redux

I face a little problem with firebase database currently. My goal is to unsubscribe a listener attached to the firebase database, this is the crucial code sample:

```
const statusHandler = () => {//logging if user is online.
        var ref = firebase.database().ref(`users/${PersonalId}/onlineState`);
        ref.on('value', function(snapshot){
            ref.onDisconnect().set(false);
            ref.set(true);
        });
        store.subscribe(() => {//redux listener to state change, if state gets changed this part of code gets executed
            var userToken = store.getState().auth.token;
            if(userToken == null){
                console.log("DETECTED")
                ref.off()
            }
        })
    };
```

So far so good, as soon as I change the redux store I trigger ref.off() and in theory since now the listener should be not listening anymore. (by the console.log("DETECTED) I know that my code works)
The problem is that I have a crucial command ref.onDisconnect() which should set a value in my database to false when I disconnect from the database, but his ref.onDiconnect() doesnt get triggered at all.

It seems as my ref.off() eventually stops the listener but the ref.onDisconnect() inside the listener which should get executed is getting ignored. Is the only way to somehow overcome this problem to change the last part of the code to this?:

```
if(userToken == null){
    console.log("DETECTED")
    ref.set(false); //set value in firebase to false quickly before detaching listener next line
    ref.off()
   }
```

Im still learning to handle listeners and thats why I dont quite understand why my code above is not working in the way intended.

Comment: I haven't tested this, but I suspect that the `.on` method is stored and is being called regardless of the `.off` that is seen later as these are async methods but are not blocking compared to traditional methods.

Comment: @DIGIByte so you basicly assume that my .off is not even canceling my .on listener? How should I call my .off in a different way then so that it will stop my .on listener?